# Converting .so file of linux to a .dll file of windows

Tags: c, dll, ctypes

I have some C code (having various header files and a make file) compiled as a `.so` file in Linux(Ubuntu) and a `python` program which calls the functions of this shared object using `Ctypes`. Now, I want to use this program on windows. In windows, `Ctypes` needs a `.dll` file instead of `.so` in linux.

So, is there a way in which I can convert the `.so` files of linux into `.dll` files to be used with `Ctypes` in Windows ?

Comment: Re-compile on windows or with windows as targeted OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You will need to recompile the library for Windows.

Comment: The section on [Linking Against DLLs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html#dll-link) has nothing to do with the OP's requirements. He has an .so file, which is completely useless with Windows Python, and thus he absolutely must follow your first recommendation to recompile and relink as a Windows DLL. He's not trying to generate a Cygwin or MinGW compatible import library from an existing DLL.

Comment: Correct, i just scrolled through the text, my bad, reference removed.

Comment: @uraimo: Thanks. I will try the dlltool. Alternatively I was trying installing mingw on linux and compiling the code into a dll to be used on windows. Will that work ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that ("crosscompiling", alternatively use mingw on windows).

Comment: I've removed the reference to dlltool entirely, as it's not an alternative to recompilation.

Comment: Sorry, little confused, how would I recompile a .so file on windows to get a .dll if I dont have the source code, just the .so?