# Converting .so file to .dll file

Tags: dll, .so

> I need to convert .so file to .dll so that I can use .dll file in windows?
>   Please let me know in case of any solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this post:
[Converting .so file of linux to a .dll file of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723100/converting-so-file-of-linux-to-a-dll-file-of-windows).

So no, the only solution is for you to recompile the library for Windows.